# Copy stucture's ref-type members by value

Tags: c#, value-type, reference-type

I have an structure and a class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string name;
}

public struct MyStructure
{
    public MyClass classValue;
    public int intValue;
    public MyStructure(MyClass classValue, int intValue)
    {
        this.classValue = classValue;
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }
}
```

Elsewhere I write the following code:

```
MyClass class1 = new MyClass() { name = "AA" };
MyStructure struct1 = new MyStructure(class1, 4);
MyStructure struct2 = struct1;
struct1.classValue.name = "BB";  //struct2.classValue.name also change!
```

How can I make sure that every reference type member of a structure is copied by value in cases such as this?

Comment: `struct` was not a good choice for `myStructure`. That's the root of the problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman is correct.  Why do you want `struct` semantics for this?  There are good reasons to use `struct`s, but the situations are very specific.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336935/c-sharp-automatic-deep-copy-of-struct

Comment: @HenkHolterman Maybe you should explain why you don't think `MyStructure` should be a `struct`. It consists of one object reference and one `Int32`. As it is written, it is a mutable `struct`, but that's not related to the question. It could be made immutable. Same behavior will be found for `KeyValuePair<int, MyClass>` which is a `struct`.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl Would changing to a `class` help him? No. He seems to want a deep copy, and a `struct` does not give him that. A class does not even give him a shallow copy (it just gives a new reference to the same object), so it's not really closer to what he wants. It sounds like he chose `struct` because he wanted copy-by-value semantics. This is the valid reason to choose `struct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyStructure` consists of an object reference of type `MyClass` and an `int` (`Int32`). The assignment

```
MyStructure struct2 = struct1;
```

copies just those data, the reference and the integer. No new instance of `MyClass` is created. You can't change that.

If you want to copy, you can say

```
MyStructure struct2 = new MyStructure(
    new MyClass { name = struct1.classValue, },
    struct1.intValue
    );
```

Of course, if you need to do this a lot, you can write a `Clone()` method to do just this. But you will have to remember to use the `Clone` method and not just assign.

(By the way, the `MyStructure` is a "mutable struct". Many people discourage them. If you mark the fields of `MyStructure` as `readonly`, I think "many people" will be satisfied.)

**Addition:** See also [Answer to *Can structs contain references to reference types in C#*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/945708/1336654).

Comment: It's far less dangerous for a struct to have fields that allow piecewise mutation, than for a struct to encapsulate state in objects that may be mutated.  It's fine for a struct to have the *identity* of a mutable class object as part of its state (as would be the case with e.g. a `KeyValuePair<string, Form>` but structures which encapsulate the state of a mutable object as part of their own state tend to have very confusing semantics.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator will not deep-copy a reference-type field inside of a struct.  You can create your own copy constructor that will perform the deep-copy manually, however:

```
public MyStructure(MyStructure structure)
{
    classValue = new MyClass() { name = structure.classValue.name };
    intValue = structure.intValue;
}
```

Then call the copy constructor using:

```
MyStructure struct2 = new MyStructure(struct1);
```

Alternatively, you could change `MyClass` to a struct.

Comment: I also thought about changing `MyClass` to a struct. But it seems like he needs to "mutate" `MyClass` instances, so making it a `struct` would lead to a "mutable struct" which many people consider evil.

Comment: Structs nested within *mutable exposed-field* structs work nicely; from a performance standpoint, the fields of the inner struct may be accessed as though they were simply fields of the outer struct.  Structs which are encapsulated as properties of other types or read-only fields work less well, the system will have to make a redundant copy of such structures to access any properties thereof.