# What is copy constructor and when it should be used in c#?

Tags: c#, constructor, copy-constructor

Actually i didn't understand the concept of it, meaning that why and when it should be employed. Usually, we can assign values to an instance of a class but why we should send an object to another object like this :

```
    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rectangle r1 = new rectangle(50, 70);
        rectangle r2 = new rectangle(r1);
    }



class rectangle
{
    private int length;
    private int breadth;


    public rectangle(rectangle x)
    {
        length = x.length;
        breadth = x.breadth;
        MessageBox.Show("I'm a Copy Constructor. \n Length= " + length.ToString() + "\n breadth= " + breadth.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: It´s a simple way to copy your rectangle. From the outside this is not possible because your properties are private. Also you could modify your rectangle or something like that.

Comment: Well, I may have seen it used in some libraries but that's not a common sight in C#. Copy constructors are the obvious cornerstone of C++ programming, but in C# they are nothing more than a fancy(but proper) way to organize [deep cloning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)( at least that what I would expect from it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy constructor versus Clone()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345389/copy-constructor-versus-clone)

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible approach to fully or partially initialize an object copying members' values from the source object.

In your case, you can call this as *mapping objects*.

Alternatively, `rectangle` class could implement a static method like `CreateFrom` that would work as the current constructor and it would also work like a factory method:

```
class rectangle
{
    private int length;
    private int breadth;

    public static rectangle CreateFrom(rectangle x)
    {
        rectangle r = new rectangle();
        r.length = x.length;
        r.breadth = x.breadth;

        return r;
    }
}
```

...and maybe this way you find your event handler code more interesting:

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rectangle r1 = new rectangle(50, 70);
    rectangle r2 = rectangle.CreateFrom(r1);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't CreateFrom have a return r?

Answer (score 1):

A copy constructor is a concept from borrowed from `C++`: the only purpose of this constructor is to make a copy from the existing object. Additionally, the compiler defines the copy constructor in `C++` automatically (implicit copy constructor) if the programmer does not provide one. And you can mix: for classes with special copy behaviour, you provide the copy constructor. For other classes, the implicit copy constructor calls your customized one, if the class has members of this type.

*Summary: the copy constructor in `C++` is a simple way to copy objects and it members. The trick is that you don't have to provide one explicitly and it is supported at compiler level.*

As far as I know, there are no implicit copy constructors in `C#`. Instead of this special constructors, you can use cloning in `C#`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects), for example.

Another note: `structs` are copied on assigment, but not recursive. Even there is [no implicit copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336935/c-sharp-automatic-deep-copy-of-struct), its only a simple memory copy.

For C++ copy constructors, see [section 12.8, page 288 in the C++14 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) for example.